# Encryption & Decryption a File in c

Tags: c, linux

Here I have a simple code for Encryption & Decryption a File in C as below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Encrypt(char * FILENAME, char * NEW_FILENAME)    
{
    FILE *inFile;   //Declare inFile
    FILE *outFile;  //Declare outFile
    char Byte;
    char newByte;
    int n;
    int i=0;

    inFile = fopen(FILENAME,"rb");
    outFile = fopen(NEW_FILENAME, "w");

    if(inFile == NULL || outfile == NULL){
        printf("Error in opening file");
            return 1;
    } else {
        printf("\nFile Opened, Encrypting");
        while(1){
                while ( !feof( inFile ) ){
                    Byte=fgetc(inFile);
                    newByte=Byte+25;
                    fputc(newByte,outFile);
                } 
            printf("End of File");
            break;
        }
        fclose(inFile);
        fclose(outFile);
    }
}

int Decrypt (char *FILENAME, char *NEW_FILENAME)
{
    FILE *inFile; //Declare inFile
    FILE *outFile; //Declare outFile

    char Byte;
    char newByte;
    int i=0;

    inFile = fopen(FILENAME,"rb");
    outFile = fopen(NEW_FILENAME, "w");

    if(inFile == NULL || outfile == NULL){
        printf("Error in opening file");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("File Opened, Decrypting");
        while(1){
            printf(".");
            while ( !feof( inFile ) ){
                Byte=fgetc(inFile);
                newByte=Byte-25;
                fputc(newByte,outFile);
            } 
            printf("End of File");
            break;
        }
        fclose(inFile);
        fclose(outFile);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char encFile[200];
    char newencFile[200];
    char decFile[200];
    char newdecFile[200];

    int choice;

    printf("Enter 1 to Encrypt  / 2 to Decrypt");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter the Source Filename:  ");
        scanf("%s",encFile);
        printf("Enter the Destination Filename:   ");
        scanf("%s",newencFile);
        Encrypt(encFile, newencFile);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Enter the Source Filename:   ");
        scanf("%s",decFile);
        printf("Enter the Destination Filename:   ");
        scanf("%s",newdecFile);
        Decrypt(decFile, newdecFile);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code works but at the end of file it also contain `"ÿæ"` such characters so it can't open in default text-editor in linux & becomes useless to store private details. I want to get same to same stuff back in the discript file. 
Please help for the same, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of topic, but please note that if your code succeeds at opening inFile but fails to open outFile, the inFile handle is not closed properly.

Comment: Sorry but this is very naive Encryption... Wouldn't it be better for you to use existing library instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: harjuo: there is nothing any problems to open any file

Comment: This isn't encyption. What's your real problem?

Comment: @Devid Heffernan: then any other method for encryption?

Comment: For the purpose of learning how to program, this encryption is probably good enough. It's simple to understand, and if something goes wrong, you can analyze it easily. When you don't want to learn *programming* but want to actually *encrypt* things, it's obviously bad.

Comment: @Heet What is your real problem?

Comment: @Heet: How about when someone tries to run this algorithm on a drive without having a write access to it? Opening outFile will fail, and the inFile handle will be left open, consuming resources and fooling the OS to believe the file is still open in the application that runs this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I explain the solution to the above code,
Let me tell you these things first. Beaware of unneccessary defination of variables in your program. 
I see lots of memory wastage in your code.Everyone can write a program but the one makes it more simpler gets the crown.Remember that when you work on programming.

I see Unneccessary variable i,defination in your Encrypt and Decrypt functions. and There is no need to go for a new byte char defination You can sort off make it as

```
   byte=byte+25 \\ even that makes your work no need of Newbyte char variable.
```

Erase the int n,int i definations to make your code better.And the most important thing you really got to know is

```
    you cannot use char a;a=getc(Filepointer);
```

remember the EOF returns -1 when it reaches to the end of file and if your using a char .It doesnot work. Char data type can only handle positive data .Even if you assign -1 to char, it internally saves it as positive number you can check that thing on google.

```
      so never use char data type for checkin EOF use int datatype
```

and as Ronald mentioned you make it as

```
       while((Byte=getc(Filepointer))!=EOF)
```

Thats the error you made.Make it as int datatype.And please check the previous questions.Becuase its actually a duplicate question.Some people can Treat as downvote.

The better style for encrypting and decrypting is using bitwise operations rather than addition

```
            Byte=Byte^200; To encrypt  \\ just a sample 
            Byte=Byte^200; To  decrypt \\ you can make more complicated
```

That how you gotta do. It gives you more security compared to adding 25 to your ACSII char.YOu can even encrypt it giving some predefined rules to it.Hope you got the answer and solved you problem.Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not correct. You probably expect that the encrypted file has the same size as the original file, but this is not the case. The faulty code is:

```
    while(1){
        printf(".");
        while ( !feof( inFile ) ){
            Byte=fgetc(inFile);
            newByte=Byte+25;
            fputc(newByte,outFile);
         } 
         printf("End of File");
         break;
    }
```

It must instead be:

```
while ((Byte = fgetc(inFile)) != EOF) {
  newByte = Byte + 25;
  if (fputc(newByte, outFile) == EOF) {
    /* ERROR */
  }
}
printf("End of File\n");
```

Note that the `printf` statement ends with a newline character (`\n`). This is a style which you should follow. Otherwise the output may not show up immediately because of buffering.

Some more details: the `feof` function only checks if the *end of file marker has been set*. But when the `fgetc` function notices that it has reached the end of file, this marker has not been set yet. Instead, the `fgetc` function returns `EOF` in that case.

Oh, and please change the types of your variables.

```
char Byte; /* this is wrong. */
int Byte; /* this is correct. */
```

See any *good* introductory book on Programming in C for the details.

Answer (score 2):

What about this new program that uses a different logic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char src[50], tgt[53], ch;
    printf ("Enter file name: ");
    gets (src);
    fs = fopen (src, "r");
    if (fs == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error while opening file!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    sprintf (tgt, "%s.ed", src);
    ft = fopen (tgt, "w");
    while ((ch = fgetc (fs)) != EOF)
        fputc (~ch, ft);
    fclose (fs);
    fclose (ft);
    remove (src);
    rename (tgt, src);
    return 0;
}
```

There is no need to write separate functions/programs for both the purposes. Also, the same file will be encrypted by printing the one's complement of a file to another file and renaming the new one to the older one after deleting the older one.

Overall: This is very **simple** utility!

Answer (score 0):

when I enter the key to decrypt the file it gives me raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken can you please check it for me as soon as possible

```
from IPython.display import display, FileLink
import os
import io
import base64

def encrypt_file(file_content, key):
    cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
    encrypted_content = cipher_suite.encrypt(file_content)
    return encrypted_content

def decrypt_file(file_content, key):
    cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
    decrypted_content = cipher_suite.decrypt(file_content)
    return decrypted_content

def handle_file_upload(change):
    uploaded_files = file_upload.value
    if uploaded_files:
        try:
            for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
                file_name = uploaded_file['name']
                file_content = uploaded_file['content'][0]  # Retrieve the file content

                if mode_dropdown.value == "Encrypt":
                    # Generate a random key for encryption
                    key = Fernet.generate_key()

                    # Convert file content to bytes
                    if isinstance(file_content, str):
                        file_content = file_content.encode()
                    elif isinstance(file_content, int):
                        file_content = str(file_content).encode()
                    elif isinstance(file_content, io.BytesIO):
                        file_content = file_content.getvalue()

                    # Encryption
                    encrypted_content = encrypt_file(file_content, key)
                    encrypted_file_path = f"encrypted_{file_name}"
                    with open(encrypted_file_path, "wb") as encrypted_file:
                        encrypted_file.write(encrypted_content)
                    display(FileLink(os.path.abspath(encrypted_file_path)))
                    print("Encryption Key:", key.decode())  # Print the key for future reference
                    result_label.value = "Encryption successful."

                elif mode_dropdown.value == "Decrypt":
                    # Check if a key is provided
                    if not key_input.value:
                        result_label.value = "Error: Encryption key is required for decryption."
                        return

                    # Decode and pad the token
                    if isinstance(file_content, int):
                        file_content = str(file_content).encode()
                    token = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(file_content + b'==')

                    # Decryption
                    key = key_input.value.encode()
                    decrypted_content = decrypt_file(token, key)
                    decrypted_file_path = f"decrypted_{file_name}"
                    with open(decrypted_file_path, "wb") as decrypted_file:
                        decrypted_file.write(decrypted_content)
                    display(FileLink(os.path.abspath(decrypted_file_path)))
                    result_label.value = "Decryption successful."

        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            result_label.value = f"Error: {str(e)}"
    else:
        result_label.value = "Error: No file uploaded."

file_upload = widgets.FileUpload(accept='*', multiple=True, description='Upload File:')
mode_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=['Encrypt', 'Decrypt'], description='Mode:')
key_input = widgets.Password(description='Encryption Key:', placeholder='Enter key')
result_label = widgets.Label()

file_upload.observe(handle_file_upload, names='value')

display(file_upload, mode_dropdown, key_input, result_label)
```

Comment: thanks you guys so much but i have another problem with different code it is about image processing code   i want to download 20 images but it takes more than half an hour and it did not display any thing also i want it as 3 stages satge 1 when sobal filter apply once 2-when sobal filter applied two times 3-when sobal filter applied three times .
please contact with me if you did not understand i will send the specific requirement file

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35293123)